# Can I make a Drupal menu item link to a different node each month automatically?

Tags: php, menu, drupal-7, hook

I have a content type with a field that associates a node with a month and year. I want an item in my main menu to always link to the node associated with the current month. How do I do this? There doesn't seem to be a hook that will let me change the link before it's printed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you dynamically add the menu item with [menu_link_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7), I'm not 100% sure if this will work for you, but in theory it should just be adding the item

```
menu_link_save(array(
    'link_path' => [drupal_get_normal_path][2]('path/to/monthly/content'),
    'link_title' => 'my custom monthly link',
    'menu_name' => 'menu_name_where_we_add_this_to'
));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom module that creates a path such as `current-month` using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), then create a function that determines the current months node and use [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) to redirect users to that node.

This way you don't have to worry about hooking into and modifying the menu.

Comment: This would work to get the user to the right page, but I really want the menu to link to that page directly too.